# Python re.findall print all patterns

Tags: python, regex, findall

```
>>> match = re.findall('a.*?a', 'a 1 a 2 a 3 a 4 a')
>>> match
['a 1 a', 'a 3 a']
```

How do I get it to print

```
['a 1 a', 'a 2 a', 'a 3 a', 'a 4 a']
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think using a positive lookahead assertion should do the trick:

```
>>> re.findall('(?=(a.*?a))', 'a 1 a 2 a 3 a 4 a')
['a 1 a', 'a 2 a', 'a 3 a', 'a 4 a']
```

[`re.findall`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns all the groups in the regex - including those in look-aheads. This works because the look-ahead assertion doesn't consume any of the string.

Answer (score 6):

You may use alternative [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex/2013-06-26) module which allows overlapping matches:

```
>>> regex.findall('a.*?a', 'a 1 a 2 a 3 a 4 a', overlapped = True)
['a 1 a', 'a 2 a', 'a 3 a', 'a 4 a']
```

Comment: It'll be nice if/when that module ever replaces the default `re` module

Comment: @JonClements Yeah! I would love it. To all the benefits this module offers, it is also well supported. I found a bug and reported to the module developer. It was fixed in 24 hours.

Comment: searched for it too and never knew there is a "regex" module better than "re"

Answer (score 5):

```
r = re.compile('a.*?a') # as we use it multiple times
matches = [r.match(s[i:]) for i in range(len(s))] # all matches, if found or not
matches = [m.group(0) for m in matches if m] # matching string if match is not None
print matches
```

gives

```
['a 1 a', 'a 2 a', 'a 3 a', 'a 4 a']
```

I don't know if it is the best solution, but here I test every substring reaching to the end of the string for matching with the given pattern.